# ItemsControl Freezes UI on Element Generation

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have an ObservableCollection binded to a ItemsControl inside a PivotItem.
I've made it so the ObservableCollection gets items added silently, only triggering the notificationchanged when it's done.

The Problem comes when generating the items. I've tested the codebehin and everything is completed in a timely manner, however the UI freezes when the items are generated.

This is the template for these ItemsControls:

```
                <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TempCell}" />
                        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>
```

The problem seems to be with ItemTemplate, even if i add an empty control to the DataTemplate associated with it, it freezes the UI. Not if there is no ItemTemplate.

I'm adding several thousands controls, that will all be displayed at once, simple ToggleButtons 25x25 in size.

I've ran very similar code in WPF, before converting it to UWP and had no freezing issues.
The application runs smoothly after the generation process.

On request here's the addition code:

```
    'Keep in mind that the item generation happens in a separate thread
    Await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, Sub() List.Replace(Output))
    'That's why it has to replace the old collection with the new one silently
    'This code does not produce any bottleneck in WPF
    Public Sub Replace(list As IEnumerable(Of T))
        If list Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("list")
        End If

        _suppressNotification = True
        Clear()

        For Each item As T In list
            Add(item)
        Next

        _suppressNotification = False
        OnCollectionChanged(New Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))
    End Sub

    'Scratching the code above and just trying this, i get the same result, it freezes the UI as UWP elements are being generated, here they are added one by one, which should cause notificationchanged events to occur.
    Await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, Sub() 
            List.Clear()
            For Each Item In Output
               List.Add(Item)
            Next
    End Sub)

    'These are the items generated, they refer to a global Random, changing it to a local Random, does not impact the freezing one way or the other.
    Parallel.For(0, CellsCount, Sub(i) Output.Add(New Cell With {.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, CByte(Random.Next(0, 256)), CByte(Random.Next(0, 256)), CByte(Random.Next(0, 256)))}))
```

Comment: Show code behind, where item collection gets generated

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] project. Such simple code as you showed above should  not lead issue.

Comment: I've updated the Question